# Why there is a factor 2/3 added to Clarke Transform matrix?

Tags: matrix

Apparently, the matrix to transform the 3 vectors \$ U_a  , U_b, U_c \$ into \$ U_\alpha, U_\beta \$ is:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} U_{\alpha} \\ U_{\beta} \\ U_{0} \\ \end{bmatrix} =   
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} \\ 
0 & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\ 
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\ 
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} U_{a} \\ U_{b} \\ U_{c} \\ \end{bmatrix}
$$

Why in Clarke Transform, matrix is multiply by \$\frac{2}{3} \$

$$ T_{\alpha \beta 0} = \frac{2}{3} 
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} \\ 
0 & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\ 
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\ 
\end{bmatrix} $$

[image: Clarke Transform]

Comment: Very simple: otherwise the amplitude of the alpha and beta vectors would not correspond to the amplitude of the three phase vectors.

Comment: I'm sorry for my superficial knowledge! I don't really understand what you mean by "correspond". 
If we add a factor 2/3 to the alpha, beta components, then the sum vector of  Ua,Ub,Uc does not equal the sum vector of Uα,Uβ!  Could you please explain more on this?

Answer (score 3):

If you do the transform without the 2/3 scale factor, the amplitude of the alpha-beta variables is 1.5 times higher than that of the ABC variables.  The scaling is done only to maintain the amplitude across the transform.  For example, taking a balanced 3-phase system having amplitude 1, the first row becomes
$$
\cos{\omega t}-\frac{1}{2}\cos{(\omega t+\frac{2\pi}{3})}-\frac{1}{2}\cos{(\omega t-\frac{2\pi}{3})}
$$
Using the identity 
$$
\cos{A}\cos{B} = \frac{1}{2}\cos{(A+B)} + \frac{1}{2}\cos{(A-B)}
$$
this is reduced to 
$$
\cos{\omega t} - \cos{(\frac{2\pi}{3}})\cos{\omega t} = \frac{3}{2}\cos{\omega t}
$$

Comment: Oh because of the phase different π/3 , the resulting total vector will be 1.5 times longer than the phase vectors. This is for sure! We just scale everything in the αβ plan with 2/3 so that they look similar in term of magnitude. And this applies only to sinusoidals with π/3 phase differences. Is that right?    Anyway, I still don't see the benefit compare to drawbacks (more calculation, easily misunderstood) when we scale like this.. Lol.. This cost me 5 hours last night trying to see what's wrong.. :-)

Comment: there should be a correction to user28910's answer. all values inside the cos() should be +/- 2*pi/3, not pi/3

Comment: dang....fixed it.

Comment: In general this is true for any odd $n$-phase system, you need a factor of $2/n$ to compensate.